# Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution initially created using VS2010. When I opened it using VS 2012, it asked me to do some conversion, which I agreed. Now I'm using VS 2010 to open the solution again, and when I tried to build it gave an error:

> error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected

How can I fix it? For example, is there a way to change the `platform toolset` to v100 again?

Comment: Project + Properties, General, Platform Toolset setting.  Click around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes indeed it is:

- Right Click project
- Select Properties
- Select Configuration Properties
- General
- Platform Toolset

When you get to Platform Toolset, click on the `v110` value which will be in the right column.  You will see a drop down appear which will allow you to select `v90`, `v100`, or `inherit`.  Of course, `v100` is the correct answer.  Once `v100` is selected, I don't believe you can back to `v110` from within VS 2010.  You would have to once again open in in VS 2012 to move it back to `v110`.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem but there is no 'general' option showing up for me. It only shows 'Configuration' under configuration properties?

Comment: @silent, get the properties of your project, not your solution.

Comment: In VS 2010 it's in the properties window, click on the tiny small button top left.

Comment: One of the reasons to fall into this condition could be building our project in a higher version of vs studio, and then trying to build again in vs10. I've got rid of it just by changing Platform Toolset back to v100 (for v10 in my case), from Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General, settings.