# Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm very new to Visual Studio. I have a project which needs v110 platform tools, so I installed Visual studio 2012, but while building project it throws the error saying:

> Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid

I even checked "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets", But I found only v90 and v100 folder but not v110 folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663898/specified-platform-toolset-v110-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click projectSelect PropertiesSelect Configuration PropertiesPlatform Toolset

When you get to Platform Toolset, click on the v110 value which will be in the right column. You will see a drop down appear which will allow you to select v90, v100, orinherit. Of course, v100 is the correct answer. Once v100 is selected, I don't believe you can back to v110 from within VS 2010. You would have to once again open in in VS 2012 to move it back to v110.

Is the answer of another thread, but I don't know how to link it by mobile app.